# Registration of the app failed - .Net Maui

Tags: c#, maui

I have a brand new maui project that I'm trying to build/debug. When I press F5 it gives me this error:

> Registration of the app failed. [0x80070005] error 0x80070005: Opening file from location: AppxManifest.xml failed with error: Access is denied.

I'm using an Admin account on Windows 11. The project was made using .Net 6 and Visual Studio Community 2022.

Comment: Please provide more information. Which platform are you trying to debug on? When does the error occur, during the build or during the deploy steps? AppxManifest.xml is for UWP, right?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it but I'm not sure the solution will work for everyone. My project was on my G drive, which is exclusively managed by Google Drive. I haven't had issues before with any C# projects but for some reason Maui had trouble with that. Anyways, after moving it to another hard drive it worked perfectly.